# Looking for a word like "eulogy", but for a person that has not died?

Tags: single-word-requests, british-english

I was thinking of words like the "background" of a person? Their overall qualities summarised into a short form. Eulogy might be a bad example, as it implies praise. **A word meaning "a summary of someone's traits and characteristics."**

Comment: http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/eulogy

Comment: How about *summary*?

Comment: A **biosketch**?

Comment: if you don´t like Josh61's *praise* or *living eulogy*, because you don't want to imply "praise", perhaps you can use *description*, *portrait*, *account*, *depiction* or as Jake says, *summary*

Comment: Like a "personality profile"? Behavioral traits or physical traits?

Answer (score 2):

Nevermind...got stuck on "eulogy" and missed the whole point of not implying praise.

Would "encomium" suit your purposes?

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/encomium

Comment: Easily confused with [meconium](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/meconium)

Comment: Let me assure you, _not_ easily confused with _meconium_.

Comment: Came here to post this myself. "Encomium" is the perfect counterpart to "eulogy".

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like a **tribute** or **testimonial**

From WordNet 3.0

> **tribute**
>
> n 1: something given or done as an expression of esteem [syn: {tribute}, {**testimonial**}]

From gcide

> **[Testimonial](http://gcide.gnu.org.ua/?q=testimonial&define=Define&strategy=.)** (?), n. [Cf. OF. testimoniale, LL. testimonialis, L. testimoniales (sc. litterae). See Testimonial, a.]
>   1. A writing or certificate which bears testimony in favor of one's character, good conduct, ability, etc., or of the value of a thing.
>
> [1913 Webster]

Answer (score 1):

A ***[Praise](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/praise) :***

> - spoken or written words about the good qualities of someone or something : an expression of approval for someone or something.

(M-W)

Answer (score 0):

If it's meant to be an honest assessment, how about "appraisal"? If you are looking for something a little more arty, "character sketch" might fit the bill.

Answer (score 0):

How about ***[vita](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/vita)***?

> A brief biographical sketch.

(mirriam-webster.com)

Answer (score 0):

*Their overall qualities summarized into a short form:*

**bio** bi·o /ˈbīō/ informal, noun –[Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=bio&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=bio%20definition)

> a biography or short biographical profile of someone.
>   "the latest in a series of unauthorized bios"

*Well, their bio says they like rock climbing; maybe we can get them to change that light bulb at the top of the stairs?*