# A eulogy for someone who isn't dead?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

What's the word for speech that talks about someones achievements, their character etc, like you would in a eulogy, except they're not dead.

For example, they might be receiving an award.

What do you call this speech?

Comment: You could call it a [***homage***](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/homage?s=t) *- something done or given in acknowledgment or consideration of the worth of another*

Comment: @Centaurus Thanks. I can't actually mark it as dupe as it doesn't have an accepted answer.

Comment: @Centaurus: True, but unfortunately, not one of the eight answers to [Looking for a word like “eulogy”, but for a person that has not died?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/262754/) has even a single upvote, and the OP hasn't accepted one either. So we can't cite it in a dup closevote.

Comment: @FumbleFingers That's why I didn't closevote it.

Comment: I've always been a fan of "roast"... but that's usually only for when you're poking fun at them along with celebrating their achievements.

Comment: Besides not having an upvoted answer, the other question also specifies "not implying praise", which means it's looking for quite a different class of words.

Comment: I'd call it a **tribute** ("something (as ... a formal attestation) that indicates the worth, virtue or effectiveness of the one in question," per Merriam-Webster) or a **testimonial** ("an expression of appreciation: TRIBUTE," again per MW). Fans of the film version of _The Wizard of Oz_ may recall the Wizard's comments to the Tin Woodman: "Back where I come from, there are men who do nothing all day but good deeds.  They are called phila- eh, phil- um, yes, uh-  good-deed-doers. And their hearts are no bigger than yours.  But they have one thing you haven't got: a testimonial."

Answer (score 4):

I think the word "[*paean*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/paean)" might fit the bill.  Originally a hymn to a Greek deity, it now means a speech of extravagant praise.  It has the added benefit that the subject may listen to it.

Answer (score 3):

*Encomium* is a good word for this.

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/encomium

> encomium
> [en-koh-mee-uh m]
>
> noun, plural encomiums, encomia  [en-koh-mee-uh]
>
> 1. a formal expression of high praise; eulogy:
>
> An encomium by the president greeted the returning hero.

Answer (score 0):

Would **conferment** work?

> Noun (plural conferments)
>
> The act of conferring; a presentation

- [YourDictionary.com](http://www.yourdictionary.com/conferment)

Which is a ceremony where *conferral* takes place

> Conferral : to give (something, such as a degree, award, title, right, etc.) to someone or something

- [Merriam-webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/conferral)