# What do we call when we speak a few good words about someone and saying why we admire that person on an occasion like birthday

Tags: terminology

We are in a birthday party  and a group of friends want to speak about the relationship they share with the birthday boy.They talk why they admire him and about the virtues of that birthday boy.what do we call it?

Comment: How do *search results* relate to the answers you'd like to receive?

Comment: 'Singing his praises', and synonyms. 'Paying tribute to'. 'Giving an accolade'. I think 'praise' should have been looked up, then the synonyms sought out, so I don't think an 'answer' is appropriate.

Comment: Probably a duplicate of [looking for a word like eulogy but for a person that has not died](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/262754/looking-for-a-word-like-eulogy-but-for-a-person-that-has-not-died/262873#262873).

Comment: It sounds as simple as giving a speech or giving a toast, unless I'm misreading the question...

Answer (score 2):

A "[**tribute**](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/tribute)" would be talking about why they admire him and about his virtues:

> [expressing] "respect or admiration for someone, or a formal event at which respect and admiration are expressed."

(Cambridge Dictionary)

Answer (score 1):

Verb, to praise:

- laud
- celebrate
- extol
- exalt

Noun, the act of praising:

- exaltation
- celebration